# PyGame MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event not registering?

Tags: python, pygame

I am recreating minesweeper in pygame for my programming class, and I am having trouble with registering when the player clicks. I have a function called `get_move(board)` that takes in the game board as a parameter and does the following:

```py
def get_move(board):
    click = None
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.button == 1: #Left click = 0
                click = 0
            if event.button == 3: #Right click = 1
                click = 1
    if click != None:
            for row in range(len(board.cells)):
                for col in range(len(board.cells[row])):
                    if board.cells[row][col].rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                        return ((row, col), click)
```

This function is being called at the beginning of my game loop as so:

```py
while in_game:
        move = get_move(board)
        ...
```

However, the clicks very rarely register, and only register once in a while when I rapidly press the mouse button. Any ideas as to what might be going on?
Here is the full code (setup is a separate file I have that handles classes and basic setup functions). I replaced the event loop with `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`, and it appears to be working:

```py
import setup
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
def main():

    zero = pygame.image.load("Pictures/0.png")
    one = pygame.image.load("Pictures/1.png")
    two = pygame.image.load("Pictures/2.png")
    three = pygame.image.load("Pictures/3.png")
    four = pygame.image.load("Pictures/4.png")
    five = pygame.image.load("Pictures/5.png")
    six = pygame.image.load("Pictures/6.png")
    seven = pygame.image.load("Pictures/7.png")
    eight = pygame.image.load("Pictures/8.png")
    nums = [zero, one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight]

    unopened = pygame.image.load("Pictures/Unopened.png")
    flag = pygame.image.load("Pictures/Flag.png")

    in_game = True
    difficulty = int(input("Choose a difficulty (1-3): "))
    if difficulty == 1:
        n = 10
        size = 9
    if difficulty == 2:
        n = 40
        size = 16
    if difficulty == 3:
        n = 99
        size = 22
    SURFACE = pygame.display.set_mode((40 * size, 40 * size))
    mines = setup.generate_mines(size, n)
    board = setup.Board(mines)
    setup.print_matrix(mines)
    ## Fill the board's cells
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for row in range(len(board.mine_matrix)):
        for col in range(len(board.mine_matrix[row])):
            num = board.mine_matrix[row][col]
            width = 40
            height = 40
            visible = False
            flagged = False
            board.cells[row][col] = setup.Cell(num, x, y, width, height, visible, flagged)
            x += 40
        x = 0
        y += 40
    while in_game:
        move = get_move(board)
        board = update_board(board, move)
        for row in range(len(board.mine_matrix)):
            for col in range(len(board.mine_matrix[row])):
                cell = board.cells[row][col]
                if not cell.visible and cell.flagged:
                    pic = flag
                elif not cell.visible and not cell.flagged:
                    pic = unopened
                elif cell.visible and not cell.flagged:
                    pic = nums[cell.num]
                SURFACE.blit(pic, cell.rect)
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                in_game = False


def get_move(board, old_click=None):
    click = None
    """
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.button == 1: #Left click = 0
                click = 0
            if event.button == 3: #Right click = 1
                click = 1
    """
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]
    if click == 1 or click == 3:
        mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        for row in range(len(board.cells)):
            for col in range(len(board.cells[row])):
                if board.cells[row][col].rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                    return ((row, col), click)

def update_board(board, move):
    if move != None:
        row = move[0][0]
        col = move[0][1]
        click_type = move[1]
        cell = board.cells[row][col]
        if click_type == 1 and cell.flagged == False:
            if cell.num == 9:
                print("game over")
            else:
                open_cell(row, col, board)
        print(board.cells[row][col].visible)
    return board

def open_cell(row, col, board):
    board.cells[row][col].visible = True
    if board.cells[row][col].num == 0:
        if row - 1 >= 0:
            if board.cells[row - 1][col].num == 0 and board.cells[row-1][col].visible == False:
                open_cell(row - 1, col, board)
            elif board.cells[row - 1][col].num != 9 and board.cells[row-1][col].visible == False:
                            board.cells[row-1][col].visible = True
        if row + 1 < len(board.cells):
            if board.cells[row + 1][col].num == 0 and board.cells[row+1][col].visible == False:
                open_cell(row + 1, col, board)
            elif board.cells[row + 1][col].num != 9 and board.cells[row+1][col].visible == False:
                            board.cells[row+1][col].visible = True
        if col - 1 >= 0:
            if board.cells[row][col-1].num == 0 and board.cells[row][col - 1].visible == False:
                open_cell(row, col-1, board)
            elif board.cells[row][col - 1].num != 9 and board.cells[row][col-1].visible == False:
                            board.cells[row][col-1].visible = True
        if col + 1 < len(board.cells[row]):
            if board.cells[row][col+1].num == 0 and board.cells[row][col+1].visible == False:
                open_cell(row, col + 1, board)
            elif board.cells[row][col + 1].num != 9 and board.cells[row][col+1].visible == False:
                            board.cells[row][col+1].visible = True

        if row + 1 < len(board.cells) and col + 1 < len(board.cells) and board.cells[row + 1][col + 1].num != 0:
            board.cells[row+1][col+1].visible = True
        if row + 1 < len(board.cells) and col - 1 >= 0 and board.cells[row + 1][col - 1].num != 0:
            board.cells[row+1][col-1].visible = True
        if row - 1 >= 0 and col + 1 < len(board.cells) and board.cells[row - 1][col + 1].num != 0:
            board.cells[row-1][col+1].visible = True
        if row - 1 >= 0 and col - 1 >= 0 and board.cells[row - 1][col - 1].num != 0:
            board.cells[row-1][col-1].visible = True


main()
```

Comment: Do you have any other event loop in your code? (I've noticed a similar problem when I had two different event loops.) In any case, it may be helpful to post your entire code.

Comment: I just added the rest of my code. Yes, I do have more than one event loop. I updated the code to use `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` instead, and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried the `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` approach, but it wasn't as versatile (e.g. just having whether the button is pressed down doesn't tell you if the button was clicked---pressed down and released). I would recommend using a class with a method which handles pygame events. It might look like this:

```
class get_move_class():

    def __init__(self):
        self.click = None

    def handle_event(self, event, board):
        self.click = None
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.button == 1: #Left click = 0
                self.click = 0
            if event.button == 3: #Right click = 1
                self.click = 1

        if self.click != None:
            for row in range(len(board.cells)):
                for col in range(len(board.cells[row])):
                    if board.cells[row][col].rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
                        return ((row, col), click)

        # Return something
        return None
```

And then the loop in `main` would have:

```
# Instantiate the class
obj_get_move = get_move_class()

while in_game:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        move = obj_get_move.handle_event(event, board)

    ...
```

To me, this approach seems less intuitive than your solution, but I think it handles the event loop better, can more easily be adapted for other events, and doesn't freeze up the loop.

Comment: it can be done even as function `get_move()` or `handle_event()` in Player class but this is not important in problem. More important thing is - which you show in code - it has to be only one `for event` and it has to be outside `handle_event()` or `get_move()`. +1